# Get the apps context?

Tags: android

Im trying to use sound pool, and Im trying to load a sound, but it wants the app context, how can I find this? Im trying to implement it in another class that implements FREFunction.

So how can I get the context?

Thanks

Comment: getApplicationContext()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to access Application context in the same activity the use **getApplicationContext()**, else if you are trying to pass this into different class then you can pass **getApplicationContext()** and take this in other class as a **Context** variable.

Answer (score 0):

getApplicationContext()

Even you do not explicitly define app context this App class is defined for you by default , if you want you can also extend it

Comment: Does not work, Context theContext = getApplicationContext(); The method getAppilcationContext is undefine.

Comment: can you provide some code ? what is the definition of your class ?

Comment: FREFunction is teh definition of my class.

Comment: do you extend something like view or activity ?

Comment: No, im making a native extension for adobe air

Answer (score 0):

**getApplicationContext()** if **self** is an **Activity**. Otherwhise you have to pass the variable.